# Google Calendar EventReminder using days

Tags: google-calendar-api

I'm using google calendar api v3, for an calendar integration project and I've succeeded in creating calendars, events and even EventReminder. But I'm facing a little issue.

I created an EventReminder using this source code :

```java
Event e = new Event();
int reminderMinutes = 1;
EventReminder reminder = new EventReminder();
reminder.setMinutes(reminderMinutes);
reminder.setMethod("popup");
List<EventReminder> l = new ArrayList<EventReminder>();
l.add(reminder);
e.setReminders(new Reminders().setOverrides(l));
e.getReminders().setUseDefault(false);
```

And now I am wondering if it is possible somehow to create an EventReminder using days instead of minutes, without converting it into minutes (like 1 day is 1440 minutes).

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no special method for setting reminder in days, only you could do is using the 
`setMinutes` method  or what you could do is that you may create a custom method of your own, for converting days into minutes like
`int minutes;`
`public int getMinutes(int days)`
`{`
`minutes = days * 24 * 60;`
`retutn minutes;`
`}`
and you may use it as following, 
`EventReminder reminder = new EventReminder();`
`reminder.setMinutes(getMinutes(1));`

Comment: Thank you that's what I thought.